# Only local DNS isn't working

Tags: 16.04, networking, server, dns

I have an Ubuntu 16.04.2 server running at home.

My Ubuntu Desktop and all other devices have working/fine DNS.

They cannot communicate with the server via hostname. And the server cannot communicate with them via hostname. However, the server can see the outside world (`ping www.google.com`) just fine.

Only local DNS isn't working, and only on my Ubuntu server.

---

Output of /etc/nsswitch.conf:# /etc/nsswitch.conf

```
 #
 # Example configuration of GNU Name Service Switch functionality.
 # If you have the `glibc-doc-reference' and `info' packages installed, try:
 # `info libc "Name Service Switch"' for information about this file.

 passwd:         compat
 group:          compat
 shadow:         compat
 gshadow:        files

 hosts:          files dns
 networks:       files

 protocols:      db files
 services:       db files
 ethers:         db files
 rpc:            db files

 netgroup:       nis
```

---

Here's the output of /etc/network/interfaces

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto enp2s0
iface enp2s0 inet dhcp
```

---

/etc/resolv.conf shows the same DNS servers as my other network devices...

Comment: i'm sure this isn't the problem, but perhaps verify your ISP isn't doing something malicious; I did have a similar problem when using verizon fios, as they were hijacking my dns lookups. This can (with some effort) be disabled. https://hackercodex.com/guide/how-to-stop-isp-dns-server-hijacking/  (Though I'm sure it's something far more mundane like dns settings in the router or ubuntu networking.)

Comment: Possibly related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/23011/why-can-i-ping-via-ip-address-but-not-hostname